# Is it possible to automate flutter gherkin test automation on CI/CD tool or remote server?

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, bdd, gherkin, flutter-integration-test

I have implemented automated tests in flutter using flutter gherkin and cucumber using flutter_gherking library. I am not sure if it's possible to run all these integration tests in any CI/CD tools i.e codemagic or anywhere else. The goal is to automate and run all integration tests in a remote system before pushing it to production. Any workaround or steps will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use bitrise or firebase.

If your tests are written using flutter integration test you can follow [this documentation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test).

If you use bitrise, before running the "Xcode test" step you may need to run:

```
flutter build ios --config-only integration_test/foo_test.dart
```

in the flutter build step.